# Searching for UPnP devices using SSDP

Tags: upnp, ssdp

I want to search for my media player on the network. Am I right in thinking it is done using SSDP m-search?

Also, when I switch the device on, will it broadcast its availability? How do I go about listening for that broadcast, and how do I send the m-search query?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to search for my media player on the network. Am I right in thinking it is done using SSDP m-search?

Yes.

> Also, when I switch the device on, will it broadcast its availability?

Yes

> How do I go about listening for that broadcast, and how do I send the m-search query?

You need to bind to the UDP multicast group `239.255.255.250:1900`. The `M-SEARCH` query is sent to the same address.

Answer (score 1):

Both.

In general, a UPnP device will advertise itself from time to time via a NOTIFY message.

At the same time, other devices can broadcast an M-SEARCH message to ask local devices on the network if they meet it's query, and if so, will/should cause those devices to re-advertise themselves again.

So yes... you could do a search for your media player via an M-SEARCH message, looking for a urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:1

As for how you send an M-SEARCH query... UDP multicast is the protocol SSDP uses, so sending a broadcast message via that depends on the language & libraries you are using.